# Can I load two separate tdb datasets on Fuseki server and query only one at a time?

Tags: bigdata, sparql, jena, fuseki

I have two datasets - A and B. At a time, I query only one dataset (say A). Meanwhile, I need to update dataset B. Once B is updated, I need to query only dataset B now and start updating dataset A.

**Need help on:**
(1.) Loading dataset A and B as 2 separate graphs so that they can be updated separately.
(2.) Disabling/Enabling datasets so that the query is directed to only the desired one.

Both the datasets A and B are very large .nt files that need to be indexed using tdbloader before loading on the graph.

I know how to create dataset using TDB loader and load datasets in the default graph, but in that case it queries union of both datasets

Comment: If you want to update offline with tdbloader (TDB1?), then it will need a server restart. For TDB2, you may be able to update graph A in place if it can be done in a single transaction. TDB2 transactions scale better. One question though - how big is " very large .nt files" in triples?

Comment: @AndyS The files are around 75 GB when compressed. On uncompressing, its a folder with small .nt files consuming around 1 TB of space. Both datasets A and B will consist of the same number of .nt files resulting in a 1TB dump

Comment: And what's the total line count of the NT files? This is the triple count.
FYI: The TDB2 loader (tdb2.tdbloader) has a argument "--loader=parallel" which is the fastest loader for the largest data.

Comment: @AndyS More than 150 million triples. How do I load both datasets as 2 different graphs and allow fuseki to query only one of them?

Comment: An RDF dataset is an unnamed, default graph and zero or more named graphs. You can load your graphs into separate datasets (databases) and they will have different URLs. http://host:port/data1, http://host:port/data2. Or you can load two different graphs in the same dataset, using different graph names, then use the query , with GRAPH, to choose which graph.